# Loading whole body of a different page with html()

Tags: jquery

I'm a newbie to jQuery.

Trying to load the whole body of a different page of my site with html(), where in the following example, "htmlb" holds the whole body.

I can see that the HTML was loaded correctly via AJAX and the body extracted alright, too, beforehand.  Also worth noting, that the HTML is well-formed, is rather short and validates perfectly in the W3 validator:

```
var eb=$('<html>').html(htmlb); 
alert($(eb).html);
```

The alert shows some weird JavaScript function instead of the body's HTML.

Judging from other threads in this forum, it should actually work?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance...

Comment: This seems to work perfectly, too:

alert($(htmlb).html());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
alert($(eb).html());
```

html() is a function.

Comment: Thanks very much!  Now works like a charm - what a stupid mistake!

Comment: I'm using the selector $('<html>') to introduce a new node, as I don't want to re-use the DOM of the current page. $('html') produces undesired results...

Answer (score 1):

```
// don't use the angle brackets, that makes a new element
var eb=$('html').html( htmlb );

// use parentheses to call the function
alert( $(eb).html() );
```

The jQuery docs are a great resource; here are the links for the [`.html()` function](http://api.jquery.com/html/) and the [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/).

For element selectors, the jQuery syntax derives directly from the css syntax: you simply use the element names. e.g. to select all `<div>` elements, simply do `$('div')`.

Answer (score 0):

By doing `$(eb).html` you're just alerting the contents of the `.html` function.

To use it, you want to do:

```
alert($(eb).html());
```

With those extra parantheses after `html` to call the function.

In your first line, you don't want to use the angle brackets, as that will make a new HTML element rather than select the `html` tag:

```
var eb=$('html').html(htmlb); 
alert($(eb).html());
```

Comment: I want to introduce a new node - works perfectly now - thanks!

Comment: Ah okay, but don't add two `html` elements! Add the content of your other page into the `html` element of the initial page.